# I have a table that retrieved documents each day. There are multiple entries each day, I want to summarize how many documents there are each day:

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that displays.

| Date | Count of Docs |
| --- | --- |
| 2023/01/01 | 1 |
| 2023/01/01 | 3 |
| 2023/01/01 | 1 |
| 2023/01/02 | 1 |
| 2023/01/02 | 2 |
| 2023/01/03 | 1 |

How do I summarise how many documents there were each day? Here is what I tried.

```sql
SELECT 
    FORMAT(DateReceived, 'yyyy/MM/dd') AS 'Date',
    COUNT (Items) AS 'Count of Docs'
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY DateReceived
```

Comment: If your DateReceived is a date+time column you need the format also in the group by: GROUP BY FORMAT(DateReceived, 'yyyy/MM/dd')

Comment: *"Here is what I tried."* So what was wrong with that attempt as, presumably, it didn't do what you want. It appears you want to `SUM` not `COUNT`. I also recommend *not* using `FORMAT` in the query; if you want to have a specific format for your dates, define that in the presentation layer.

Comment: Side note, don't use single quotes (`'`) for aliases. Single quotes are for literal strings, not delimit identifying object names. They can also result in some "gotchas" as their behaviour is not consistent depending on where they are referenced. Also some syntaxes with literal string aliases are deprecated. Stick to object and alias names that don't need delimit identifying, and if you *must* delimit identify them use the T-SQL identifier, brackets (`[]`), or ANSI-SQL's, double quotes (`"`).

Comment: Please show your desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your answer, You can try following:

```
SELECT 
    FORMAT(DateReceived, 'yyyy/MM/dd') AS 'Date',
    SUM (Items) AS 'Count of Docs'
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY FORMAT(DateReceived, 'yyyy/MM/dd')
```

*use `SUM` instead of `COUNT`
and Correct `GROUP BY` Statement*